# SonarQube VSTS extension pull request commenting

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

The [SonarQube docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) specify:

> When analysis is triggered from a Pull Request the **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis** task decorates the updated source code in the Pull Request with the new code quality issues, instead of pushing the analysis report to the SonarQube server.

How can you turn this on? We are using TFS 2018 with version 3.x of the SonarQube TFS/VSTS extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis task is deprecated now and it can not be used.

The workaround is execute `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end` command manually.

You can queue your build by the private agent which installs [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).